# jquery dropdown selector AutoPostback

Tags: asp.net, jquery

In jQuery is there any way to distinguish between postbacking dropdowns and non-postbacking ones(ASP.NET 3.5):

```
$('select').change(function(e)
{
        //something like this
        if ($(this).attr('AutoPostback') == true) 
        { 
           //do something here  

        } 
       else  
        { 
          //do something else 
        }
```

Think have to call server side function from script here to determine AutoPostback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, a dropdown that is going to postback will have an onchange attribute that contains something like "__doPostBack(" though there will also be some other stuff in there.

So you could do something like the below, which I didn't test so hopefully there is no typos

```
$('select[onchange*="__doPostBack("]').change(...your handler for postbacking control...);
$('select:not([onchange*="__doPostBack("])').change(...your handler for non-postbacking control...);
```

Comment: There is a typo, but if you do 'select[onchange*="__doPostBack"]' then it's all great, thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

The AutoPostBack attribute, IIRC, is server-side. In otherwords, it's parsed by the server and never actually makes it to the browser.

It'd be a bit redundant code-wise, but you could give it a cssClass="AutoPostback" and then check for that via jQuery

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yeah, I know it's a server side that's why I said I probably have to call a server-side function here from selector

Comment: Well, come to think of it, most controls set to do auto-postback are doing so via javascript, so perhaps there's a way to check for that.

Comment: Yes, turns out there is, see reply above

Answer (score 0):

I came upon this thread a little late but perhaps someone else along the way will find this useful.

I also was having issues getting the jquery ui selectmenu to do a postback.  the previous comments got me pretty close but errors came up when i ran it.  This may be due to the different version i am using but my final fix was to attach the postback to the change event a little differently.  I had to pass strings to the postback call instead of the actual element. First parameter is the ID of the select element and the second perameter is the name of the server side function that is supposed be called.

```
$("#cboStateFilter").selectmenu({
    change: function (event, ui) { __doPostBack("cboStateFilter", 'cboStateFilter_SelectedIndexChanged'); }
});
```